# How to insert values from my database to my entries? Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I'm trying to insert some values from my database to my entries. I have a main interface with the same code working well, but I've created a secondary window and tried to make work almost the same code but it's not working. It gives me this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

This is my code:

```py
myid = StringVar()
myname = StringVar()
myowner = StringVar()
mycel = StringVar()

id_entry = Entry(windows2, textvariable=myid)
name_entry = Entry(windows2, textvariable=myname)
owner_id = Entry(windows2, textvariable=myowner)
cel_id = Entry(windows2, textvariable=mycel)

btn_search = Button(windows2, text='SEARCH', command=lambda: search())
btn_search.place(x=930, y=12, width='60', height='26')

def search():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db1.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM regis WHERE idcard=" + myid.get())

    theuser = c.fetchall()

    for user in theuser:
        myid.set(user[0])
        myname.set(user[1])
        myowner.set(user[8])
        mycel.set(user[9])

    conn.commit()

    if theuser:
       messagebox.showinfo(title='ID Found', message='User found')

    else:
       messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Wrong ID')
```

Comment: Print out value of `myid.get()` before executing the SQL statement to see whether it has the value you expected.

Comment: @acw1668 It shows me the same error, It's hilarous becase I tried to use the same code which is working well in my first windows, but in my second windows isn't working

Comment: Most likely you used `Tk()` as your second window.  Use `Toplevel()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 wow mate, it's working now, I haven't thought about that =D

Comment: @acw1668 but I don't know why my messagebox is opening in the first windows, I mean when I push **search** button it shows **user found** but in my main windows

Comment: @acw1668 I've solved it with `messagebox.showinfo(title='ID Found', message='User found', parent = windowsname)` , Thank you buddy.

Comment: Another suggestion: use placeholder in SQL statement like `c.execute("SELECT * FROM regis WHERE idcard=?", [myid.get()])` in order to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I've edited it just now with the advice you gave me and it's working well. Thanks mate, apreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

What you should be doing is adding a `master` argument to ALL tkinter widgets. When we create `Tk()`, it creates a `tcl` interpreter. Each `tcl` interpreter has its own memory for its widgets. So when you say `StringVar()`, it doesn't know which `tcl` interpreter to belong to, so it implicitly uses the first created `Tk()`. But the first created `Tk()` might not hold the widget you are associating your `StringVar` to(with `textvariable`), so it will not have its value stored.

**Solution:**

What you can do is, either explicitly mention which instance of `Tk()` to belong to, or use `Toplevel()` for the creation of child windows(like mention by acw1668).

```py
StringVar(master=newwindow) # Same with other tkinter variables and all widgets too
```

or

```py
newwindow = Toplevel() # Recommended because tkinter was made to work like this?
```

Also make sure to sanitize your inputs so it wont be prone to SQL injections:

```py
c.execute("SELECT * FROM regis WHERE idcard=?",(myid.get(),))
```

---

Though I would never use `StringVar` for entry widgets as long as I have to use `trace` on them. They have their own `get()` method which works the same way.